# Rails 4 show loading spinner for csv file and hide spinner after download complete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, csv, turbolinks

I have given link for downloading csv file from index action. After clicking the link I need to show spinner image since it is taking long time for downloading csv file.

I'm able to show loading spinner by calling on click jQuery function like below.

```
 $("#csv_link").on('click', 'show_spinner');
```

Now my question after csv file download is completed how can I remove this loading spinner ?

because in controller action I am using `send_data` method to download csv file.

So I'm unable to call any thing like render `:js => "hider_spinner"`.

Since it is throwing double render error.

Could anybody please suggest me solution?

Thanks